# Live-code view - How to Prevent Auto Saving and Uploading to the Server when CTRL-Z is Pressed

Tags: automation, dreamweaver, undo

Unfortunately after swearing to never use the hunk of garbage that is Dreamweaver again, after 7 years - I found a need for some WYSIWYG editing and installed the complete hunk of garbage software on my machine.

I simply knew there would be some disaster awaiting, so I was being really meticulous about backing up.

But I got caught not backing up for about 4 hours, and lost those 4 hours of work to yet another of the endless array of bugs that will completely destroy your work when using Dreamweaver.

I was using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> multiple times when suddenly the code went all weird and blocks of code went missing, and it looks like sections were just cut in mid line - and it just went from ugly to uglier. I recognized this nightmare form 7 years ago - the exact same reason why I stopped using this garbage software to begin with and swore to never use again. Right now I am wishing I kept my promise to myself.

So I was really careful not to save the document, but the fun thing is - every time I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> - Dreamweaver is "conveniently" saving the file to the server.

I do want live updates as I hit "Save" or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, but I DO NOT want anything saved when I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>!

So knowing that I want to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, and knowing Dreamweaver is complete garbage and will crash and kill my code.

**How do I turn off automatic saving when I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>?**

As a secondary question - how about how do I prevent losing my code again with this hunk of garbage software?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have auto-save AND auto-sync turned on together, and auto-save might have ran shortly after you undid changes, following which the file was uploaded to the server by auto-sync.

Simply switch off auto-save so that only a manual save will trigger an upload.

---

Also another option that may accidentally revert your changes is the Auto Recovery feature, that reverts your file to an incorrect state when Dreamweaver crashes (or encounters a bug). If auto-sync is switched on as well, that may cause a corrupt file to be uploaded.

Simply switch off Auto Recovery so that no corrupt files will be uploaded.

Comment: Looking into this - and thank you - in the mean time - if you do not mind me asking... what do you think of Dreamweaver?

Comment: I used to use Dreamweaver ten years+ ago. Now I recommend [Webflow](http://webflow.com) for frontend dev if you need a WYSIWYG editor. It's not free to export but it's definitely worth the hours of frustration saved.